# Как искать регионы города по почтовому индексу на google maps

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps, geocoding

Использую google maps для геопоиска места на карте и отметке на нем маркера. Возможно ли делать конкретный поиск по индексу города, например в каждом городе есть множество индексов почтовых и при вводе одного из этих индексов получать метку на карте города того района где привязан данный индекс.